# Translating this line of code?

Tags: perl, translate

I have a little bit of translating I have been working on, from Perl to just plain old English. I was wondering if I had translated this line correctly.

```
open(FQ, $fqFile =~ /\.gz$/ ? "gunzip -c $fqFile |" : $fqFile)
    || die"Cannot open the pipe to $fqFile\n";
```

My translation:

```
#Open a file, $fqFile, by either unzipping it first or just opening it if already unzipped.
```

Comment: I believe `gunzip -c` does not alter the original file.

Comment: note that this breaks if the filename contains shell metacharacters

Answer (score 1):

You are perfectly right. If the filename in `$fqFile` ends in `.gz`, then the file is unzipped (to stdout) and then read as a pipe. Else the filename is taken as is and the file is opened the normal way.

Side note: `gunzip -c` doesn't change the file (in place), it unzips to stdout. Thus the `open()` call with the trailing `|`. It runs the given "filename" `gunzip -c $fqFile` as a *command* and reads its output.